Tomcat ignore metadata-complete="true" with servlet 6.1
My application does not use any servlet annotations. That I want skip the scanning for annotations. But it look like that Tomcat 11.0 ignore the metadata-complete="true"attribute. Do I have to handle this differently with servlet version 6.1? Is this a bug in Tomcat 11.0?
My file WEB-INF/web.xml starts with:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<web-app xmlns="https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/jakartaee" 
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
         xsi:schemaLocation="https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/jakartaee web-app_6_1.xsd" 
         version="6.1"
         metadata-complete="true">

The log output is:
INFORMATION [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/11.0.0]
INFORMATION [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR Deploying web application archive [foobar.war]
FEIN [main] org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner.scanResourcePaths No TLD files were found in resource path [/WEB-INF/].
FEIN [main] org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner$TldScannerCallback.scan No TLD files were found in [file:....
...
INFORMATION [main] org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner.scanJars At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.



Please describe in your words what you thought that "TLD" is. This is namely in no way related to annotations.

I think TLD stands for Tag Library Descriptor. My understanding was that this tags are define via annotations. But I can be wrong because we does not use it. I see that it need some time for scanning and read in the message that it can be skip. How can skip it?

Nope. It are physical *.tld files which define custom JSP tags. One famous example is JSTL. Zero relation to annotations. As to Tomcat's JAR scanner config, just read the manual: https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-11.0-doc/config/jar-scan-filter.html

In the file META-INF/context.xml I have set:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Context>
    <JarScanner>
        <JarScanFilter pluggabilityScan="" pluggabilitySkip="*.jar" tldScan="" tldSkip="*.jar"/>
    </JarScanner>
</Context>

and now there is no more scan.
